# Utilize parallel processing on for loop

Tags: python

I have written a script that reads server names from a file, command names from other files, and run all the commands on all servers and print the output.

```
import os, paramiko
cmdlist =[]

with open('command.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        cmdlist.append(line.rstrip())

with open('server.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        server = line.rstrip()
        username, password = ('root', 'password')
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()
        ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
        ssh.connect(server, username=username, timeout=60)
        print "For Server " + server
        for y in cmdlist:
            ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(y)
            output1 = ssh_stdout.read()
            print ">", output1.rstrip()
        ssh.close()
```

The problem is that second for loop runs sequenally, so it takes too much time. The sequence of server don't matter. I want that I my script run commands on all servers in parallel, and then compile then in a file.

I tried something like this. I put above code in a function called "fast_process" and write code like below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()                         
    pool.map(fast_process)
```

But this seems to be ask me more arguments, but my function does not takes any argument. What can I do?

Comment: `pool.map(fast_process, range(times))`? Anyway, posting the exact traceback and the complete code helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is function that takes a function, a sequence and applies a function to each element of a sequence (simplifying a bit python version of map)

So what you need is to create a sequence of servers and apply function to them.

```
import os, paramiko

with open('command.txt') as f:
    commands = tuple(line.rstrip() for line in f)

with open('server.txt') as f:
    servers = tuple(line.rstrip() for line in f)

username, password = 'username', 'password'
pool = Pool()


def exec_commands(server):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()),
        ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
        ssh.connect(server, username=username, timeout=60)
        for cmd in commands:
            ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
            output = ssh_stdout.read()
            print('>', output.rstrip())
        ssh.close() 

pool.map(exec_command, servers)
```

Comment: The code hungs at " pool.map(exec_commands, servers)" for infinite time. I tried pool.terminate after pool.map, but it didn't help.

Comment: well, `pool.map` itself is blocking, it just processes data in parallel, so if you added `pool.terminate` after it it wouldn't help. The problem should be in `exec_commands` -> something is blocking there. You should debug it, but in any case you would probably need to add timeouts to blocking operations.